# In hive ,is partitioning fast or bucketization fast?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, partitioning

This is the interview question I faced, if we have 1 TB data in HDFS. **Which type of method** in hive gives us faster performance i.e `partitioning` or `bucketing` ?
  I told them depending upon data we choose either `partitioning` or `bucketing` .But the interviewer didn't satisfied with my answer.

What should be proper answer (along with example) for it?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct that - It really depends on the data and what exactly you want to do with the data.

`Partitioning` is used for distributing load horizontally in a logical fashion. It optimizes the performance, but sometime it could lead to partition having very less amount of the within them. This results into bad performance, as the `mapreduce` works on bigger files than many small files.

Here, `bucketing` can help, because `bucketing` guarantee that all the data for the bucketing column remains together. E.g. if we bucket the `employee` table and use `emp_id` as the bucketing column, the value of this column will be hashed by a user-defined number of buckets (which must be optimized considering number of records). Records with the same `emp_id` will always be stored in the bucket. At the same time, one bucket may have many `emp_id` together having a more optimized chunk of data for `mapreduce` processing. `bucketing` is specially helpful, if you want to perform `map-side` join.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct--

Hive partitioning is an effective method to improve the query performance on larger tables . Partitioning allows you to store data in separate sub-directories under table location. It greatly helps the queries which are queried upon the partition key(s).

Bucketing improves the join performance if the bucket key and join keys are common. Bucketing in Hive distributes the data in different buckets based on the hash results on the bucket key. It also reduces the I/O scans during the join process if the process is happening on the same keys (columns).